# jquery blinking array values in title tag

Tags: jquery, arrays, tags, title, setinterval

I have a chat feature on my website that I want to replicate the facebook functionality of blinking "new message from John" in the title tag when a new message comes in.  I can do this for one instance of a new message however I need to do this for all new messages (infinite possibility).  Therefore a setInterval loop needs to be created and cycle through the names of people who have sent a new message.  Lets assume John, Sue, George, and Katy have sent me new messages; this is what I have so far:

```
 $("div .labels").each(function(){   //.labels where each persons name is displayed in the bottom banner bar
  var senderFirstName = $(this).attr('rel');
  //this is where I need to create the array "AllNames" containing all of the sender names
 });
```

Now that I have the array "AllNames" containing all the first names of people sending me messages, I need to cycle through this array every 1500ms and change the title tag to reflect the new name.

```
 var BlinkTitle = setInterval(function(){
     $("title").text("message from " + AllNames[0]); //AllNames array needs to cycle through the array values every time the interval loops.
 },1500);
```

Please Help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just increment an index:

```
var AllNames = ['Me', 'Myself', 'Irene'];

var ix = 0;

var BlinkTitle = setInterval(function(){
    if (++ix >= AllNames.length) ix = 0;

    $("title").text("message from " + AllNames[ix]); //AllNames array needs to cycle through the array values every time the interval loops.
},1500);
```

Checking against AllNames.length will prevent you from accessing past the end of AllNames.